# Getting User-Agent with javascript not returning properly

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I'm trying to get the user-agent of the user who connects to my webpage so that I can run an extra script depending if they are a bot or not.

I'm using this to get the User-Agent:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
```

This seems to work but when I return it, it is a different value from the User-Agent I get when I go to https://www.esolutions.se/whatsmyinfo (value looks like `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)`) which is the one I need.  I also have been spoofing my browser's User-Agent and at that website it changes accordingly, with my JS, the value stays the same.  The value I'm getting is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/* Safari/537.36`

Is there a way to get the value that that website gets?

Thanks.

Comment: "I'm trying to get the user-agent of the user who connects to my webpage so that I can run an extra script depending if they are a bot or not." What kind of bot? User-Agent headers are easy to fake. Also, what value are you getting through `navigator.userAgent`? (Or, if “the value I’m getting” is that, what do you expect instead?)

Comment: What are you using to spoof the user agent? Your extension may only take care of spoofing what it sends via HTTP requests, not what `navigator.userAgent` shows.

Comment: @Ryan I'm looking for search engine/crawler bots and I'm not worried about people faking their User-Agent headers as there is no security risk or anything, just a feature that will benefit users.

Comment: @jacob I'm using a chrome extension which I thought was working properly as it spoofed correctly on that other site I linked in the OP https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-g/ffhkkpnppgnfaobgihpdblnhmmbodake

Comment: Strange, it says "This extension also changes the javascript based "navigator userAgent"; do you have an older version installed, or is this something you explicitly have to enable?

Comment: If you want to keep out bots, why not use something like `robots.txt`? Bots (like the bingbot) don't execute javascript anyway, and any bot that wants to do malicious stuff will fake itself good enough that a javascript check won't help.

Comment: If you're checking on the server, why do you care what the variable is on the client? Just check what they send in the User-Agent header.

Comment: @jacob I literally installed it 20 minutes ago and yes, you manually go to it and select which device you want to spoof as.

Comment: @somethinghere I'm not trying to keep out bots.  This is primarily for actual users, and if the bots don't trigger the javascript that works fine too, I'm really trying to detect real people I guess.

Comment: Just wondering what the purpose of this is then. If you consider some of your users bots, then do users in click farms count as bots as well? Do you want to weed those out? I think you're going to have a hard time weeding out 'fake' users...

Comment: @Barmar I'm not going to say I'm completely familiar with this topic, but what I'm trying to do is if a real person connects to the page, then they are redirected, if a bot connects, then they are not redirected but instead allowed to crawl through the data on the page.  Would my method not be the way to do it?

Comment: @somethinghere The page has data on it that I want crawlers to be able to index from, but when a user connects to the page from a search engine, I want the to be redirected essentially.  And I was thinking I needed to prevent the bot from being redirected.

Comment: I don't see why you need to check the user agent in that case. Since bots don't usually execute JS, just perform the redirection unconditionally. Bots will ignore it.

Comment: @barmar I guess that is a good point.  Are there any common cases where the bot would execute the JS and mess with the crawling process?

Comment: When they are trying to be sneaky. Otherwise, bots are pretty well behaved. Shady bots might [citation needed] execute javascript.

Comment: I think Google might execute JS, so you could check specifically for their UA.

Comment: @barmar Well now I'm back at my original problem, haha.  So is it likely that the extension I'm using to spoof my UA isn't working properly and the JS I wrote should work?

Comment: I see, you're trying to test your code by setting UA to Google's, to make sure it doesn't redirect, but it's not working. It does seem like an issue with the extension.

Comment: Based on this article (http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) it might work if you place a link on the page `<a href="..." rel="nofollow`>` and then click that link using javascript?